# Filtering XML List Object in R

Tags: r, xml, list

I'm trying to parse IRS 990 form filings that are available via Amazon AWS. Here's an example:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201541349349307794_public.xml

I'm using the XML package to read in and parse the XML document as follows:

```
require(XML)
x <- read_xml("https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form990/201541349349307794_public.xml")
data <- xmlParse(x)
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
```

The code above converts the XML to a list object perfectly. Now that I have it as a list object, I'd like to obtain the list of all names and associated information for the persons listed in the Part VII Schedule A Grp. Screenshot from the XML document (names redacted):

[image: Screen capture of XML document]

As you can see, there are several names listed (screenshot is only a sample). However, when I attempt to filter the R list object as follows:

```
xml_data$ReturnData$IRS990$Form990PartVIISectionAGrp
```

I receive only the information for the *first* name in the document. None of the others appear, despite the fact that their nodes are all listed in the document as Form990PartVIISectionAGrp.

What am I missing here? How can I return an object that contains *all* of the names and information contained in that section of the document?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider directly parsing to dataframe as those nodes are at consistent levels. However, you need to map a user-defined prefix, *doc*, for the default namespace in document.

```
library(XML)

data <- readLines("https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201541349349307794_public.xml")

doc <- xmlParse(data)

df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//doc:Form990PartVIISectionAGrp",
                                      namespaces = c(doc="http://www.irs.gov/efile")))
```

**Output**

```
df
#          PersonNm                  TitleTxt AverageHoursPerWeekRt IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd ReportableCompFromOrgAmt ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt OtherCompensationAmt OfficerInd
# 1         -------     CHAIRMAN OF THE BOARD                 16.00                              X                        0                            0                    0       <NA>
# 2         ------- ASSISTANT SECRETARY/BOARD                  8.00                              X                        0                            0                    0          X
# 3         -------              BOARD MEMBER                  8.00                              X                        0                            0                    0       <NA>
# 4         -------    SECRETARY/BOARD MEMBER                 16.00                              X                        0                            0                    0          X
# 5         -------              BOARD MEMBER                  8.00                              X                        0                            0                    0       <NA>
# 6         -------                       CFO                 16.00                           <NA>                        0                            0                    0          X
# 7         -------             PRESIDENT/CEO                 40.00                           <NA>                   110886                            0                    0          X
```